# Pull/Get all commits of other repository

Tags: git, github

I have this repository:
https://github.com/DaniellMesquita/Pokemon-Showdown-Server-Template
With all files of this other:
https://github.com/Ecuacion/Lumen-Pokemon-Showdown
But I need keep the history of original authors of these files. How can I Pull/Get all branchs/commits of the second repository to merge in my first repository? Which is the command?

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell:

1. Delete old remote:
   `git remote rm origin`
2. Add the new remote: `git remote add origin git@github.com:DaniellMesquita/Pokemon-Showdown-Server-Template.git`
3. push all changes: `git push --all origin`  &&  `git push --tags origin`

would recomend reading [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/moving-git-repository-new-server/) and [this](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/) beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

1. create a clone of Ecuacion repository

   `git clone https://github.com/Ecuacion/Lumen-Pokemon-Showdown.git`
2. go to the new repository you just cloned

   `cd Lumen-Pokemon-Showdown`
3. Change the remote to point to your repository on GitHub

   `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/DaniellMesquita/Pokemon-Showdown-Server-Template.git`
4. Push all the commits to your repository on GitHub

   `git push origin --all --force && git push origin --tags --force`

---

ps: What you probably want, though, is to DELETE your repository from GitHub, and create a fork of the Ecuacion repository... Just hit the **Fork** button on their repo and you will get an exact copy which you can then clone to your machine.

[image]